# How can I calculate mod 97 in ms-access 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have this dividend `3298` that I need to return `0.00` when divided by `97`

Right now, I'm doing this `Me.mod_97_txt = 3298 / 97` but this is returning `34`

Comment: [Mod Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the modulo operator, that is, 3298 Mod 97.